# How to change the Variant of Lightning Button on click of Button in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to change the variant in when the lightning button is clicked. How can i change the variant when I toggle between the button?

**JS Code**

```
showMonthly(event) {
    this.showMonthlyData = true;
    event.target.variant='brand';
    this.showYearlyData = false;
    this.yearlyBrand = 'neutral';
    alert('Monthly',this.showMonthly);
    alert(this.yearlyBrand);
    alert(event.target.variant);
}
 
showYearlyFunc(event) {
    event.target.variant='brand';
    this.showMonthlyData = false;
    this.monthlyBrand = 'neutral';
    alert(this.monthlyBrand);
    alert(event.target.variant);
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <lightning-button-group>
                <lightning-button class="slds-theme_brand" label="Monthly" variant={monthlyBrand} onclick={showMonthly}></lightning-button>
                <lightning-button class="slds-theme_brand" label="Yearly"  variant={yearlyBrand} onclick={showYearlyFunc}></lightning-button>
        </lightning-button-group>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To swap two variables `a`, `b` you can leverage [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment): `[a, b] = [b, a]`, so if you store the default variant in `monthlyVariant` and `yearlyVariant` in both your methods you could just have `[this.monthlyVariant, this.yearlyVariant] = [this.yearlyVariant, this.monthlyVariant]`.
I changed the variables' name because having a variable named "somethingBrand" that holds `neutral` may confuse.

**JS**

```js
monthlyVariant = 'brand';
yearlyVariant = 'neutral';

showMonthly() {
    this.showMonthlyData = true;
    this.showYearlyData = false;
    [this.monthlyVariant, this.yearlyVariant] = [this.yearlyVariant, this.monthlyVariant];
    console.log(`Monthly: ${this.monthlyVariant} - Yearly: ${this.yearlyVariant}`);
}
 
showYearlyFunc() {
    this.showMonthlyData = false;
    [this.monthlyVariant, this.yearlyVariant] = [this.yearlyVariant, this.monthlyVariant];
    console.log(`Monthly: ${this.monthlyVariant} - Yearly: ${this.yearlyVariant}`);
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<lightning-button class="slds-theme_brand" label="Monthly" variant={monthlyVariant} onclick={showMonthly}></lightning-button>
<lightning-button class="slds-theme_brand" label="Yearly"  variant={yearlyVariant} onclick={showYearlyFunc}></lightning-button>
```

By the way, I don't think `slds-theme_brand` is a standard slds class, so unless it's a your custom css class, you could remove it.

[Demo](https://app.lwc.studio/view/3PAef1dTaQz4wK6BJH9K/src/app.html)